# Is "era" correct in "since era so far"?

Tags: word-usage

In a poem, I want to say "from the beginning of the world until now", so can I say: "since era so far"?

Is it correct? Does it have the right meaning?

If it's not correct please offer me some alternatives to "era".

Comment: 'Since era so far' is ungrammatical. Substituting a synonym would not improve matters. But please don't amend the question to ask for acceptable alternatives, as writing advice is off-topic on ELU.

Comment: I appreciate you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From Merriam-Webster:

> Synonyms age, day, epoch, period, time

(https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/era). These are good alternatives for you to check your usage.

And from Cambridge Dictionary:

> a period of time of which particular events or stages of development are typical

And it’s worth just looking a dictionary entries for era yourself as many of them have examples.

So, an era is a period of time which can be defined by a particular feature. So you *could* say "in the era of our world" or "in the era of life on Earth". But I think these are too broad to really define an era. Usually eras are defined by culture (eg the era of The Beatles or the Baroque era) or historical persons or events (eg the Industrial era). "Age" is, perhaps, better for a longer, less defined time period.

**Edit**
From discussion below, this is for a poem where the phrase "since era so far" fits the structure (rhyme and meter). The phrase "all era so far" was recommended as a replacement because it also fits the structure but fits the meaning of "era" better, "era" meaning a distinct period of time rather than a singular point in time.

Comment: thanks...but you know it's for a poem...and i need to just one word except it...is "beginning" good in this mean?

Comment: So "since era so far" fits your rhyme and meter?

Comment: exactly :)  but i can use "beginning" except the era if it is correct in this mean: from the start of the world.  what is your opinion?

Comment: "All era so far"? Era is a period of time, not a date or single point in time. I think the plural is "era", too.

Comment: really thanks pam but the last question....to show from the start of world till now is it correct: since beginning so far?

Comment: "All era so far" would mean every era until now, which would cover all the time from beginning until now. I think with artistic licence, "since beginning so far" is ok but less clear. Good luck with the poem.

Comment: yes... All era so far is great...reallllly thank :)

Comment: @Pam The plural of "era" is "eras".